# What is the difference between a = 5, a(5), a{5} and a[5] in C++?

Tags: c++, syntax, initialization, variable-assignment, assignment-operator

What is the difference between the statements of `a = 5`, `a(5)`, `a{5}` and `a[5]` in C++?

I occasionally see them used for anything like assigning a value to an object in C++ programs. Where is the difference between them?

Comment: Why do you post a question for which you have a prepared, long answer already that you post just in the same moment together with the question?

Comment: @SparkFountain To provide a Q&A for anyone who potentially encounter the issue and wonder about the syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a main difference between all of these statements in C++ in the context of initialization ( which is done at the moment of the declaration of an object) and  assignment; the last statement `a[5]` is also a completely different thing in comparison to the others.

---

Premise: If `a` is an object of a certain datatype, for example `int`, we can assign an appropriate value (according to the datatype declared with) to `a`. Note: The value may be evaluated by a valid expression, for example `a = 2 + 3;` behave the same as `a = 5;`.

---

1. `a = 5;`

This is the common assignment form used in C++ programs. It can be used either for the initialization or later assignment (after the declaration of `a`) in the respective scope. If `a` is declared properly as of type `int`, this statement assigns the integer value of `5` to the `int` variable of `a`.

It can be used either directly by the declaration:

```
int a = 5;
```

first assignment (when `a` is not initialized at its declaration):

```
int a;
// some code may exist between.
a = 5;
```

Or an assignment anywhere else in the respective scope after the first assignment or initialization at the declaration (dependent on storage class):

```
int a;          // declaration of `a`.
// some code may exist between.
a = 5;          // first assignment of `a` with the value of `5`.
// some code may exist between.
a = 7;          // assignment of the value of `7` to `a`.
```

---

2. `a(5);`

This statement initializes the `int` variable of `a` with the value of `5`. It can be used *only* at the explicit initialization at the moment of the declaration:

```
int a(5);
```

Else the compiler will high-probably throw an error, because it "thinks" that `a` would be a function.

Technically, `a(5)` could be a function, which takes the value of `5` as argument in general tough, but it is the context of the declaration of an `int` object what makes the difference here.

---

3. `a{5};`

Same as 2. It initializes `a` with the value of `5`. It can be used *only* by the initialization at the moment of the declaration:

```
int a{5};
```

Else the compiler will throw an error.

---

Note: To initialize a value like `int a{5};` or `int a(5)` is a C++ feature only. It is not possible to initialize an object in C this way.

---

4. `a[5];`

With this statement we do not apparently initialize or assigning the value of `5` to the variable of `a`. Instead, we defining an array, a cluster of objects, consisted of `5` objects, which is represented as its own entity by the identifier of `a`:

```
int a[5]; // declaration of `a` - `a` is an array of 5 int objects.
```

So, we do not have a single object here nor assigning any value to it.

Furthermore, we have to distinguish between the declaration of an array with:

```
int a[5];
```

and the later accessing to a certain `int` object of the array `a`, like fore example:

```
a[4] = 12;
```

In this case, `a[4]` is representing the `5`th object inside the array and the value of `12` is assigned to that fifth object of the array.

The number inside the square brackets, here `4`, is called the index number. Note, that the index numbers successively start at `0`. Thus, `a[0]` represents the first object in the array, `a[1]` the second, and so on. You can´t use `a[5]` in that way, if you declared `a` with `int a[5];` because it would represent, in this case, a sixth object, which isn´t allocated in memory for `a`.

Comment: `a = 5;          // initialization of a with the value of 5.` Technically, it's an assignment. Initialization must be part of the declaration: `int a = 5;`.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius My intention was to make a clear distinction for better understanding. I will edit it.

Comment: "_My intention was to make a clear distinction for better understanding._" If the "distinction" is accompanied with wrong statement - it doesn't help with the understanding.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Sorry, my bad.